# Reporting error in someone else's tree at Geni.com?

Tags: myheritage.com, geni.com

I was going through matches on Geni that seem to come from two different trees made on MyHeritage website. I primarily use MyHeritage's desktop app, so I am not paying for either of their web services. I did a quick research online to see what these are about and found that someone apparently has merged their tree with mine, because a woman with similar surname from the same region had parents with names similar to my grandfather's grandparents, who actually were born after this woman. It's a very obvious mistake and I am rather concerned about it because they've merged my living relatives into their tree as well and apparently the error is already multiplying.

Is there a way to report an error in someone else's tree?

Comment: BTW, just for the future: Geni of today is mainly about the one large shared tree with all people in there connected through blood or marriage. If an individual is connected to this tree and his profile is marked as public then anyone can make changes to this profile (unless it has been locked, which is rarely the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I e-mailed misconduct@geni.com and they removed errounosly added profiles of close relatives from MyHeritage. They also advised that there's an option to exclude profiles you manage from MyHeritage's match search by unticking a box under privacy settings > managed profiles

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to contact the person who owns the tree and try to convince them politely (and ideally with some excellent sources to back up your arguments) that you're right, and they're wrong. There is no central 'Tree Police'.

Comment: I didn't see any option to contact them on MyHeritage. I am less concerned with tree policing (I use desktop apps for a reason) than with the fact that they got data down to at least my mom in their tree that I only put into geni so I could start the tree and that was supposed to be private. They may as well have access to data of underage kids my cousins have added. Don't they really have a way to report a privacy breach given how big a deal it is these days?

Comment: Do you have a MyHeritage account? When I look at matches there I see a Contact option When you view their tree do they have details there of living individuals? Did you review https://www.geni.com/company/privacy before you added the info there?

Comment: Yes, but I am not a paying member on either of their sites and contact options are behind the paywall on both. I ended up finding suggestion to e-mail misconduct@geni.com they haven't answered, but I see customer service has updated profiles of some close dead relatives, so I guess they tried to do something about it, I still see the false matches, though

Comment: Nothing will be amended unless it's in violation of the company's privacy policy -- false matches may be a mistake but they're allowed.

Comment: I got very nice response from customer service that they've removed profiles for my mom and her siblings that were copied over to MyHeritage and advice that I can change settings to prevent them from showing ip on MyHeritage. I still see matches for some ancestors with these trees, but no other living relatives, so hopefully the issue has been solved